# Simple Trig Identity?

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

I have the equation

$\sum_1^N \cos\omega_p t\cos\omega_qt$

Where N is an even number representing the number of time steps

$\omega_p=\frac{2\pi p}{N}$  p=1,...,$\frac{N}{2}$

I need to prove the following 3 cases:

Case 1:

$\sum_1^N \cos\omega_p t\cos\omega_qt=0$

if $p \neq q$

Case 2:

$\sum_1^N \cos\omega_p t\cos\omega_qt=N$

if $p=q=\frac{N}{2}$

Case 3:

$\sum_1^N \cos\omega_p t\cos\omega_qt=\frac{N}{2}$

if $p=q\neq\frac{N}{2}$

The 2nd case is easy:

$p=q=\frac{N}{2}$ hence $\omega_p=\omega_q=\pi$

clearly when this value is substituted in

$\cos\omega_p t\cos\omega_qt=1$

and summing this N times gives N

I'm having problems with the other two cases?

Taking the 3rd case first:

$\cos\omega_p t\cos\omega_qt$

$=\frac{1}{2}[cos(\omega_p t-\omega_q t)+cos(\omega_p t+\omega_q t)] $

given in this case:  $p=q\neq\frac{N}{2}$

$=\frac{1}{2}[cos(0)+cos(2\omega_p t)]$

$=\frac{1}{2}[1+cos(2\omega_p t)]$

To get the correct answer the $cos(2\omega_p t)$ must equal zero in every case. But as far as I can see it will only happen when $\omega_p=\frac{\pi}{4}$ which will certainly not be true for all p?

Comment: This is missing a lot of details. What are you summing over? Is it an infinite sum? What are $\omega_p,\omega_q,N$?

Comment: Sorry N is the number of time steps so sums over t=1...N. $\omega_p=\frac{2\pi p}{N}$ p=1,...,N

Comment: Also we know that N is even

Comment: These clarifications should be edited into the question. It should not be necessary to read the comments in order to understand the question.

Comment: OK I will make the amendments now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$\begin{align}
\cos \omega_pt \cos \omega_qt &=\frac12(\cos (\omega_p-\omega_q)t+\cos (\omega_p+\omega_q)t)\\\\
&=\frac12(\cos (2\pi(p-q)/N)t+\cos (2\pi(p+q)/N)t)\\\\
&=\frac12\text{Re}\left(e^{i(2\pi(p-q)/N)t}+e^{i(2\pi(p+q)/N)t}\right)\tag 1
\end{align}$$

---

**CASE 1**:

Summing $(1)$ from $t=1$ to $t=N$ reveals that for $p\ne q$

$$\sum_{t=1}^N\,\cos \omega_pt \cos \omega_qt =\frac12\left(\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi(p+q)(N+1)}{N}\right)\sin(\pi(p+q))}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi(p+q)}{N}\right)}+\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi(p-q)(N+1)}{N}\right)\sin(\pi(p-q))}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi(p-q)}{N}\right)}\right)$$

which is obviously zero for $p\ne q$ since the numerators have terms $\sin (\pi(p\pm q)) =0$.  It is important to remark that the denominators are not zero since $0<p+q<N$ whenever $p\ne q$.

---

**CASE 3**:

Summing $(1)$ from $t=1$ to $t=N$ reveals that for $p=q \ne N/2$

$$\sum_{t=1}^N\,\cos \omega_pt \cos \omega_qt =\frac12\left(\frac{\cos\left(\frac{2\pi p(N+1)}{N}\right)\sin 2\pi p}{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi p}{N}\right)}+N\right)$$

which is obviously N/2 for $p = q\ne N/2$ since the numerator has the term $\sin 2\pi p =0$.  It is important to remark that the denominator is not zero since $2p<N$.

Comment: Thanks nice answer with clear explanation!

Comment: @Bazman You're welcome.  My Pleasure.  And thank you.  Your request for Case 3 is complete now.